# What does rc, in bashrc, nanorc stand for?

Tags: configuration

Is there any long-form, if at all? Or is it just a tradition from the  80's?

Comment: Similar question at unix.stackexchange: [What does “rc” in .bashrc stand for?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/what-does-rc-in-bashrc-stand-for)

Comment: Similar question on [su]: [What does the 'rc' in `.bashrc`, etc. mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/173165/what-does-the-rc-in-bashrc-etc-mean)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've heard

- run commands
- resource control
- run control
- runtime configuration

Personally, I'd go with run control, because ESR says so.

http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s03.html

His footnote says:

```
 The ‘rc’ suffix goes back to Unix's grandparent, CTSS.
 It had a command-script feature called "runcom". Early
 Unixes used ‘rc’ for the name of the operating system's
 boot script, as a tribute to CTSS runcom.
```

Wikipedia chooses "run commands" as the default long-form, but admits that context should determine word choice.

```
 While not historically precise, rc may also be pronou-
 nced as "run control", because an rc file controls how
 a program runs. For instance, the editor Vim looks for
 and reads the contents of the .vimrc file to determine
 its initial configuration. The most sensible pronunci-
 ation depends on the function of the file: to start
 something up, or to control how something starts up.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_Commands

Comment: ESR’s »runcom«, however, does not suggest »run control«, unless there is a rule for transoforming n to m that I don’t know about.

Answer (score 5):

According to this source -- http://kb.iu.edu/data/abdr.html -- it means "run commands"

Comment: See also here http://superuser.com/questions/144339/sayvimrcor-screenrc-what-does-the-rc-mean

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part1/section-3.html) gives an interesting explanation for few commands.

According to it `rc` stands for `"runcom"` which in turn stands for `Run Commands`.